# Next Prime Number based on User Input

Tags: java, methods, numbers, user-input

I have a method to check if a number is prime or not. I need to write a program that will allow a user to input a number and the program will then display the next largest prime number. Here's what I have so far... Its very brutal because I am a beginning CS student who gets the material but cannot exactly implement code in the ways that I want.

```
package nextprime;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NextPrime {

public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number / 2; divisor++) {
        if (number % divisor == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberInput;
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    numberInput = input.nextInt();
    int end = numberInput + 2;
    if (isPrime(end)) {
        System.out.println(end);
    }
    int i;
    for (i = numberInput; i < end; i++) {

    }
    if (isPrime(i)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you need help with? What went wrong when you tried it?

Comment: I just need someone to point me in the right direction. When I input any number greater than 6, I just get that number returned back to me.

Comment: its actually not returned, it just doesnt display anything

Comment: The for loop is empty so it basically just calls `if(isPrime({i,end})) { ... }` twice.

Comment: Explain your thinking. It's not clear you understand what needs to be done. It looks like you believe that you only need to look two numbers ahead, but you're not even doing that.

Comment: what is the point of `end = numberInput + 2`.

Comment: Sam, if this is a homework assignment, I suggest going to a TA or the teacher. Being a previous professor, students get caught on Stack Overflow quite easily.

Comment: i need a number that will look ahead to at least the next prime number. I have modified my code and believe I have found the solution but in some cases it is displaying the next 2 prime numbers:

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the logic with `end`, maybe you need to have a boundary. If not, then you can remove the `end` logic and replace your `for` loop with something like:

> for (i = numberInput; !isPrime(i); i++);

Or you can use a `while` loop, like:

`public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberInput;
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    numberInput = input.nextInt();
    if (isPrime(numberInput)) 
      numberInput++;
    while (!isPrime(numberInput))
      numberInput++;
    System.out.println(numberInput);
  }`

Comment: is that how you get a for loop to run if the method returns false? We havent technically learned that yet so I was hesitant to look that up and use it.

Comment: @Sam Yes, that is a way, but see my updated answer for an alternative, may be easier, at first.

Comment: how would I get it to display the next prime number if I entered a prime number?

Comment: @Sam See my updated answer, basically you will check if the input is prime you will skip it.

Comment: thanks for your help everyone. I finally got it to run correctly! I am eternally grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    
    System.out.print("Enter a number");
    int number = input.nextInt();

    while(!isPrime(number)){
        number++;
    }
    System.out.println(number+" is the minimum prime number.");

}
```

Comment: Well, as long as isPrime works, this works, but it's relatively inefficient, since half the numbers it checks will be even. Adding an isEven check and then incrementing by 2 if it's odd would cut time spent finding it by half at the very least.

Comment: It will be much efficient to use ' <= Math.sqrt(number)' instead of '< number / 2' in boolean.

Answer (score 0):

the code is written in c#.net. You can Convert it to java. The prime no checking is done in traditional manner. you can use your own checking method. in this program no user defined function is used. all the code can be written in the main block.

```
        int number= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int counter;
        counter = 0;
        for (int divisor = 1; divisor < number; divisor++)
        {
            if (number % divisor == 0)
                counter++;
        }
        if (counter == 1)

            richTextBox1.Text = number.ToString() + " is a prime number";
        else
        {
            number++;

            while (number> 0)
            {
                counter = 0;
                for (int divisor = 1; divisor < number; divisor++)
                {
                    if (number % divisor == 0)
                        counter++;
                }
                if (counter == 1)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = "Next prime numbere is " + number.ToString();
                    break;
                }

                number++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but the question is about Java, so C# code is definitely off-topic here.